# Redundant field in SQL for Performance

Tags: sql, database

Let's say I have two Tables, called Person, and Couple, where each Couple record stores a pair of Person id's (also assume that each person is bound to *at most* another different person).
I am planning to support a lot of queries where I will ask for Person records that are not married yet. Do you guys think it's worthwhile to add a 'partnerId' field to Person? (It would be set to null if that person is not married yet)
I am hesitant to do this because the partnerId field is something that is computable - just go through the Couple table to find out. The performance cost for creating new couple will also increase because I have to do this extra book keeping.

I hope that it doesn't sound like I am asking two different questions here, but I felt that this is relevant. Is it a good/common idea to include extra fields that are redundant (computable/inferable by joining with other tables), but will make your query a lot easier to write and faster? 
Thanks!

Comment: No, it won't be a good idea - this kind of denormalization would be difficult to maintain and there would be effectively zero performance gain as doing a single `JOIN` (or even creating a View using the join as a default data source) is a very cheap operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better option is to keep the data normalized, and utilize a view (indexed, if supported by your rdbms).   This gets you the convenience of dealing with all the relevant fields in one place, without denormalizing your data.

Note: Even if a database doesn't support indexed views, you'll likely still be better off with a view as  the indexes on the underlying tables can be utilized.

Answer (score 1):

Is there always a zero to one relationship between Person and Couples? i.e. a person can have zero or one partner? If so then your `Couple` table is actually redundant, and your new field is a better approach.

The only reason to split `Couple` off to another table is if one Person can have many partners.

When someone gets a partner you either write one record to the `Couple` table or update one record in the `Person` table. I argue that your `Couple` table is redundant here. You haven't indicated that there is any extra info on the `Couple` record besides the link, and it appears that there is only ever zero or one Couple record for every `Person` record.

Answer (score 0):

How about one table?

```
--  This is psuedo-code, the syntax is not correct, but it should
--  be clear what it's doing
CREATE TABLE Person
 (
   PersonId   int  not null
     primary key
  ,PartnerId  int  null
     foreign key references Person (PersonId)
 )
```

With this,

- Everyone on the system has a row and a PersonId
- If you have a partner, they are listed in the PartnerId column

Unnormalized data is always bad. Denormalized data, now, that can be beneficial under very specific circumstances. The best advice I ever heard on this subject it to first fully normalize your data, assess performance/goals/objectives, and then carefully denormalize only if it's demonstrably worth the extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nick. Also consider the need for history of the couples. You could use row versioning in the same table, but this doesn't work very well for application databases, works best in a in a DW scenario. A history table in theory would duplicate all the data in the table, not just the relationship. A secondary table would give you this flexibility to add additional information about the relationship including StartDate and EndDate.